# How to find out other user connected to the same WIFI network with which you are in android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

Here i want to ask that how can i find out other Mobile phones connected to the same Network(WIFI) with which you are connect, and display it in your Mobile phone. For example there would be an  ANDROID app where i will get all the user which is also connected with the same network?

Comment: There is no general way how to do it. You would have to connect to access point using its management protocol. And there is often no standard protocol, only HTML UI. And you have to know password for that AP, also username.
My question is, what do you intent to do with displayed list? Is list of MAC addresses enough? There is no way to get name of host on wifi.

Comment: @Pihhan here in this app, when i will connect to WIFI, then it will show me all other user connected to the same WIFI network and then i'll send some files to them, actually this is an application idea,please help  through some source code

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create an application that discovers other hosts running it over the same network ... 

You could simply send a **UDP Broadcast** to a specific port. Then all running instances of your app on the network could listen to that port and respond with a message identifying them as a host!

Comment: sorry for bumping in @Imad JAMIL, maybe you could help me....
wifi unresolved question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357892/how-to-solve-discovering-other-device-via-wi-fi-android-api?noredirect=1#comment37663295_24357892

Answer (score -1):

By using CMD...

```
net view

shutdown/I
```